# About TLS session resumption Using Ticket

Tags: ssl

I'm reading RFC 5077, and there are some questions.

client generate pre-master secret, then:

1. F1(pre-master secret, client random, server random) ==> master secret
2. F2(master secret, client radnom, server random) ==> key material

is that right?

then:

1. RFC 5077 recommend that the ticket saves the master secret, but the master secret is calculated using client/server randoms in previous session. In resumption of this session, server and client will use master-secret in ticket and new client/server random to generate new key material?
2. Since the ticket is opaque to client, so the client should remember the master secret in the session it wants to restore?

Answer (score 0):

> In resumption of this session, server and client will use master-secret in ticket and new client/server random to generate new key material?

No. A resumed session uses the same session key.

> Since the ticket is opaque to client, so the client should remember the master secret in the session it wants to restore?

Yes, so it can participate in a possible partial handshake after resumption, which presumes the same secrets.

Comment: hi, for the first question, the final encryption parameters(IV, cipher) should be calculated from master secret, client random and server random, right? then if they use the same session key, the ticket should record the client random, server random and the master secret? and the client should remember the client and server random number in last session, too?